# Reverse proxy with Python from IP outside NAT

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I have a personal PC at home, which is located outside the NAT (has a dynamic IP).

I also have a personal VPS server, which has a white IP and can accept requests.

I need a script that I will run on the server and on my personal PC at home, so that I can have a home IP from anywhere in the world by setting up a proxy in the browser.

My code works, but after opening 1-2 sites, the server seems to stop listening to the admin and, accordingly, does not forward packets to the client.

Help me fix the code, please!

Server:

```
import select
import socket
import threading

class Proxy:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = None
        self.uid = 0
        self.array = []
        self.username = 'username'
        self.password = 'password'
    
    def get_available_methods(self, nmethods, connection):
        methods = []
        for i in range(nmethods):
            methods.append(ord(connection.recv(1)))
        return methods
        
    def verify_credentials(self, connection):
        version = ord(connection.recv(1))

        username_len = ord(connection.recv(1))
        username = connection.recv(username_len).decode('utf-8')

        password_len = ord(connection.recv(1))
        password = connection.recv(password_len).decode('utf-8')

        if username == self.username and password == self.password:
            response = bytes([version, 0])
            connection.sendall(response)
            return True

        response = bytes([version, 0xFF])
        connection.sendall(response)
        connection.close()
        return False

    def handle_admin(self, connection, identifier):
        version, nmethods = connection.recv(2)

        methods = self.get_available_methods(nmethods, connection)

        if 2 not in set(methods):
            connection.close()
            return

        connection.sendall(bytes([5, 2]))

        if not self.verify_credentials(connection):
            return
            
        preamble = b'\xFF\xFE\x00\xFF'
        self.client.sendall(preamble + identifier.to_bytes(4, 'big'))

        version, cmd, _, address_type = connection.recv(4)
  
        if address_type == 1:  # IPv4
            address = socket.inet_ntoa(connection.recv(4))
        elif address_type == 3:  # Domain name
            domain_length = connection.recv(1)[0]
            address = connection.recv(domain_length)
            address = socket.gethostbyname(address)
        port = int.from_bytes(connection.recv(2), 'big', signed=False)
        
        print('[Client] ' + address + ':' + str(port))
        
        preamble = b'\xFF\xFE\xFF\x00'
        if address_type == 1:  # IPv4
            addr_bytes = socket.inet_aton(address)
        elif address_type == 3:  # Domain name
            addr_bytes = len(address).to_bytes(1, 'big') + address.encode('utf-8')
        port_bytes = port.to_bytes(2, 'big')
        
        packet2 = port_bytes + cmd.to_bytes(2, 'big') + address_type.to_bytes(1, 'big') + addr_bytes
        self.client.sendall(preamble + identifier.to_bytes(4, 'big') + len(packet2).to_bytes(4, 'big') + packet2)
        
        found_data = None
        while found_data is None:
            for number, data in self.array:
                if number == identifier:
                    found_data = data
                    self.array.remove((number, data))
                    break
            
        connection.sendall(found_data)
        print('Reply sended, len: ' + str(len(found_data)))

        t = threading.Thread(target=self.get_connection, args=(connection, identifier))
        t.start()
        
        go_break = False
        while True:
            to_remove = []
            for number, data in self.array:
                if number == identifier:
                    to_remove.append((number, data))  
                    # self.array.remove((number, data))
                    print('Get from server && Reply to admin ' + str(len(data)) + ' bytes.')
                    try:
                        connection.sendall(data)
                    except Exception as text:
                        print(f'[connection.sendall(data)] Exception! {text}')
                        go_break = True
                        break

            for item in to_remove:
                self.array.remove(item)
                print(len(self.array))
        
            if go_break:
                break
        
        try:
            connection.close()
        except Exception as text:
            print(f'[connection.close()] Exception! {text}')
        
    def get_connection(self, connection, identifier):
        while True:
            try:
                data = connection.recv(40960)
                if data:
                    if len(data) > 0:
                        print('Get from admin && Send to client ' + str(len(data)) + ' bytes')
                        self.client.sendall(b'\xFF\xFE\xFF\x00' + identifier.to_bytes(4, 'big') + len(data).to_bytes(4, 'big') + data)
                else:
                    connection.close()
                    break
            except Exception as text:
                print(f'[get_connection] Exception! {text}')
                break
        
    def connect_to_client(self, host, port):
        client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        client.bind((host, port))
        client.listen()
        
        print('[Client] SOCKS5 proxy server is running on {}:{}'.format(host, port))
        
        connection, address = client.accept()
        print('[Client] New connection from {}'.format(address))
        while True:
            if connection.recv(2) == b'\xFF\xFE':
                if not self.client:
                    self.client = connection
                    print('The client has been successfully authorized!')
                else:
                    if connection.recv(2) == b'\x00\xFF':
                        number = int.from_bytes(connection.recv(4), 'big')
                        size = int.from_bytes(connection.recv(4), 'big')
                        print('New data! Size: ' + str(size))
                        data = b''
                        while len(data) < size:
                            packet = connection.recv(size - len(data))
                            if not packet:
                                break
                            data += packet
                        print('Len: ' + str(len(data)))
                        self.array.append((number, data))
                
    def run(self, host, port):
        admin = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        admin.bind((host, port))
        admin.listen()

        print('[Admin] SOCKS5 proxy server is running on {}:{}'.format(host, port))

        while True:
            connection, address = admin.accept()
            print('[Admin] New connection from {}'.format(address))
            if self.client:
                self.uid += 1
                t = threading.Thread(target=self.handle_admin, args=(connection, self.uid))
                t.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    proxy = Proxy()
    t = threading.Thread(target=proxy.connect_to_client, args=('vps ip', 55555))
    t.start()
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=proxy.run, args=('vps ip', 44444))
    t2.start()
```

Client:

```
import select
import socket
import threading

class Proxy:
    def __init__(self):
        self.array = []

    def request(self, server, identifier):
        found_data = None
        while found_data is None:
            for number, data in self.array:
                if number == identifier:
                    found_data = data
                    self.array.remove((number, data))
                    break
        
        address = None
        port = int.from_bytes(found_data[0:2], 'big')
        cmd = int.from_bytes(found_data[2:4], 'big')
        address_type = int.from_bytes(found_data[4:5], 'big')
        if address_type == 1:
            address = socket.inet_ntoa(found_data[5:9])
        elif address_type == 3:
            domain_length = int.from_bytes(found_data[5:6], 'big')
            address = found_data[6:domain_length].decode()
        
        print('Successfull get: ' + str(address) + ' ' + str(port) + ' | ' + str(cmd))
        
        remote = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        remote.connect((address, port))
        bind_address = remote.getsockname()
        
        reply_address = int.from_bytes(socket.inet_aton(bind_address[0]), 'big', signed=False)
        reply_port = bind_address[1]

        reply = b''.join([
            int(5).to_bytes(1, 'big'),
            int(0).to_bytes(1, 'big'),
            int(0).to_bytes(1, 'big'),
            int(1).to_bytes(1, 'big'),
            reply_address.to_bytes(4, 'big'),
            reply_port.to_bytes(2, 'big')
        ])
        preamble = b'\xFF\xFE\x00\xFF'
        server.sendall(preamble + identifier.to_bytes(4, 'big') + len(reply).to_bytes(4, 'big') + reply)
        print('Send reply, len: #' + str(len(reply)))
        
        if reply[1] == 0 and cmd == 1:
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.remote_get, args=(remote, server, identifier))
            t.start()
            
            go_break = False
            while True:
                to_remove = []
                for number, data in self.array:
                    if number == identifier:
                        to_remove.append((number, data))  
                        # self.array.remove((number, data))
                        print('Get from server && Reply to remote ' + str(len(data)) + ' bytes')
                        try:
                            remote.sendall(data)
                        except Exception as text:
                            print(f'[remote.sendall(data)] [{identifier} Exception! {text}')
                            go_break = True
                            break
                            
                for item in to_remove:
                    self.array.remove(item)
                    
                if go_break:
                    break
              
        remote.close()
          
    def remote_get(self, remote, server, identifier):
        while True:
            try:
                data = remote.recv(40960)
                if data:
                    if len(data) > 0:
                        print('Get from remote && Send to server ' + str(len(data)) + ' bytes')
                        server.sendall(b'\xFF\xFE\x00\xFF' + identifier.to_bytes(4, 'big') + len(data).to_bytes(4, 'big') + data)
                else:
                    remote.close()
            except:
                break
          
    def listen_for_messages(self, server):
        try:
            while True:
                preamble = server.recv(2)
                if preamble:
                    if preamble == b'\xFF\xFE':
                        preamble2 = server.recv(2)
                        if preamble2 == b'\x00\xFF':
                            number_bytes = server.recv(4)
                            number = int.from_bytes(number_bytes, 'big')
                            t = threading.Thread(target=self.request, args=(server, number))
                            t.start()
                            print('New thread!')
                        elif preamble2 == b'\xFF\x00':
                            number = int.from_bytes(server.recv(4), 'big')
                            size = int.from_bytes(server.recv(4), 'big')
                            data = b''
                            while len(data) < size:
                                packet = server.recv(size - len(data))
                                if not packet:
                                    break
                                data += packet
                            print('New data! Size: ' + str(size) + ', Real length: ' + str(len(data)))
                            self.array.append((number, data))
                else:
                    print('Connection closed.')
                    break
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Error: {e}')
        finally:
            server.close()
            print('Connection closed.')

    def connect(self, host, port):
        server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        server.connect((host, 55555))
        server.send(b'\xFF\xFE') # Authorization
        self.listen_for_messages(server)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    proxy = Proxy()
    proxy.connect('vps ip', 55555)
```

Answer (score 0):

You origin code is:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    proxy = Proxy()
    t = threading.Thread(target=proxy.connect_to_client, args=('vps ip', 55555))
    t.start()
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=proxy.run, args=('vps ip', 44444))
    t2.start()
```

Which should be changed to:

```py
def waiting_until_complete(*threads: threading.Thread) -> None:
    for t in threads:
        t.join()


def main():
    proxy = Proxy()
    t = threading.Thread(target=proxy.connect_to_client, args=('vps ip', 55555))
    t.start()
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=proxy.run, args=('vps ip', 44444))
    t2.start()
    waiting_until_complete(t, t2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help.